# Is closing eyes at seat during lunch break acceptable?

Tags: break-time

Is it acceptable to close eyes while sitting on the chair, with back against the back of the chair, and with face stilling facing the computer screen?

Do people (at any level, high or not) often check to see whether a coworker closes their eyes? How can that be found out, if the seat is in a cubical? Is it possible and normal that a workplace may have some devices to monitor coworker? (Is the camera of the computer used for monitoring people working at it?)

Does the timing matter? Is it acceptable to do that at lunch break when not eating lunch? Is it acceptable to do that for a minute or two any time?

What is the reason behind being against that? Is the reason valid and reasonable?
Medical studies have shown that taking nap helps improve productivity.
But sitting on a chair with eyes closed is far from taking a nap.
It helps when staring a computer screen for too long.

What would you do for relaxation in the mid of work?

Thanks.

Comment: Normally we say "Where is the question" but this post is comprised almost entirely of questions... and many not answerable or off-topic IMO. What is your goal here? What issue can we help you with?

Comment: I think a moderator can do better than that.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked what is your goal here and what issue you got, in the spirit of making this post on-topic, so we (or I) can edit it into shape... please explain your goal. I'm not criticizing, just pointing out that your post could use some improvements so you can get better help. Feel free to ping me if you need help editing or improvingit... like I said, several of those read off-topic (opinion based, company specific, mainly), and even though I want to help, I can't assume your intentions and edit out all questions I see that are off-topic

Comment: Please edit any clarifications (e.g. from your comments on the answers) that are necessary/helpful in answering the question into the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

Having closed eyes on your workplace might look like you are pretending to work, but actually slacking. Taking break at breakroom might be better choice, since it is obvious you are on break and not just slacking. (But be sure to do this on your official break.)

Of course, if Kilisi is right and they are just using this just as an excuse, this won't help at all.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it acceptable to close eyes while sitting on the chair, with back
> against the back of the chair, and with face stilling facing the
> computer screen?

It's acceptable to me. But I'm not your boss, so most likely my opinion doesn't count. If you want to know if it's acceptable in your company, you should ask your boss.

> Do people (at any level, high or not) often check to see whether a
> coworker closes their eyes?

I don't know anyone at any company who routinely walks around to see if anyone is closing their eyes. Mostly, because that wouldn't be expected of people working. That said, I would expect people to notice if it happens.

> How can that be found out, if the seat is in a cubical?

It could be found out in a number of ways. If your face is visible from the walkway, if someone peeks over the cubicle walls, if someone asks a question and you have to blink to focus your eyes, etc.

> Is it possible and normal that a workplace may have some devices to
> monitor coworker? (Is the camera of the computer used for monitoring
> people working at it?)

It's possible, though unlikely in some workplaces and more common in others. It's very unlikely that your computer's camera would be used without you noticing and/or being warned first. If monitoring via a camera actually happens, it's more likely to happen via overhead surveillance cameras.

> Does the timing matter?

It might. Closing your eyes when you should be working may not be a good idea if people notice.

> Is it acceptable to do that at lunch break when not eating lunch?

In most places, what you do during your lunch break is your own business. That said, sleeping in your chair may be frowned upon. Closing your eyes might lead folks to believe you are sleeping.

> Is it acceptable to do that for a minute or two any time?

That depends on your company, your boss, your job, company rules, and the company culture.

> What is the reason behind being against that? Is the reason valid and reasonable?

You would have to ask the one that is against it.

> Medical studies have shown that taking nap helps improve productivity.
> But sitting on a chair with eyes closed is far from taking a nap.

Right. As far as I know, there are no medical studies that indicate sitting on a chair with eyes closed helps improve productivity.

> It helps when staring a computer screen for too long.

If it helps you, then you could use that as an excuse if challenged. Maybe your company will accept that for a reason, maybe not.

> What would you do for relaxation in the mid of work?

I would get up and walk a bit. During my lunch time I would take a long walk. When not during lunch, I would walk to get water or coffee, or to use the rest room.

I never closed my eyes and just sat there for relaxation. I may have closed and rubbed my eyes for a few seconds on occasion, although I don't recall doing so.

Obviously, context matters a lot. Closing your eyes for a few seconds is unlikely to be noticed, and unlikely to be unacceptable. Closing your eyes for a few hours is more likely to be noticed and unacceptable. Closing your eyes for a few seconds during your software development job is less likely to be unacceptable. But closing your eyes during your air traffic control job is more likely to be unacceptable. And closing your eyes when told not to do so is more likely to be unacceptable.

Overall, if you are concerned that closing your eyes and sitting in your chair might not be acceptable, or might be viewed as odd, ask your boss.

Comment: Thanks. Also wait for me to make a new post about being complained on wearing a winter hat in seat for a job on software engineering, and asking if having any family and friend question, while I have been very polite and considerate, which is why they felt free to make such warnings and complains and personal comments. (discrimination at its finest).

Comment: Want to know more? I just started this position this week, and have the first month as my propagation period. I never complained, and asked in advance for personal computing device rules, and followed them despite their over restricted rules (no website access, except MS and Google websites, no any other including stack exchange). during interview, I was asked if I could come at 7, before assured hat it was okay to go to work at regular hours by another interviewer. But was asked to come at 6:30 the day before my first day, and I did my best and still failed at 7:30, 9, 8, 7:45 this week

Comment: yes. autocorrection typo. Is it normal that a new job starts with a probation period? 1 month, 3 months, 6 months? What would that mean?

Comment: @Tim yes it is very common to have probation periods in several industries and jobs. It's a two-way street: it also helps you see if the company is a place where you would like to be, or if you should look elsewhere as Joe commented

Comment: @Tim Unless your winter hat is religious attire or medically prescribed, I can't see how this could be considered discrimination.

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim thanks for the information. I was wondering why the meaning of "discrimination" is narrowed so severely? Discrimination can be based on a person themselves. What contexts and layers does the word have?

Comment: @Tim When used here, it almost always refers to unlawful discrimination. While laws vary, that typically involves treating someone worse because of their disability, religion, sexuality, or other protected factors. It's relevant because you have the law backing you up.

Answer (score 1):

> Is closing eyes at seat during lunch break acceptable?

Anything that doesn't infringe on others within reason is acceptable during your lunch break including closing your eyes.

They are using it as a rationalisation. It's perfectly acceptable to rest your eyes and especially during a break. So there must be more to it that you would be taken to task over something so trivial. So discount that as the real reason and work out what the underlying problem is.

From your comments there are other trivial issues and you are within your probation period. Since no one seems interested in helping you this is a pretty clear indication that this job is not a good fit for you.

Comment: I was warned for that. It looks like picking on and discrimination against me.

Comment: @Tim, Who warns you ? HR or your manager ? What exactly are the reasons they don't want you to close your eyes during lunch break ? (It sounds like a sketch from "The Office").

Comment: @Job_September_2020 manager who was told by some VP.

Comment: He sided with whoever complained about me @JoeStrazzere. That is his boss. I then said I would pay more attention not to let that happen again. He said some similar things such as go for a walk, or book a conference room to rest there. I walk all the time, more than most people. I also think conference room is used for meeting, and it would be inappropriate for myself. I took off my winter hat immediately, so whoever complained would be satisfied. I am prepared to be told to not come back next week, whatever they don't like about me. I have already lost interest.

Comment: I felt discriminated ...

Comment: @Tim yikes, reading comments here and in other answers seems like you should consider if this is a place you would like to be. If you decide to job hunt, try to do it now while you are still employed (in probation) so the transition is smoother

Comment: They are using it as a rationalisation. It's perfectly acceptable to rest your eyes and especially during a break. So there must be more to it that you would be taken to task over something so trivial. So discount that as the real reason and work out what the underlying problem is.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I can't afford talking to a lawyer.  As for eyes, isn't it normal to rest eyes after 1 hour or 2? I remember it is recommended every 20 mins.

Comment: @Kilisi the underlying problem is discrimination especially from some "VP" whom I don't really know. Admitting discrimination is very hard, it seems. Also making unreasonable requirements such as early morning hours without making that clear during interview, while I have been doing my best to comply.

Comment: that is obvious, so there is no point worrying about this, worry about how to mitigate against the real problems

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to read between the lines and answer the real question. Unfortunately, this means you won't get the idea you're fishing for.

This has nothing to do with you closing your eyes. If you want to take a quick break to rest your eyes a couple of times an hour, go for it. My advice would be to stretch your arms while you do so- it makes it obvious this is a quick refocus rather than napping and it's good to do anyway.

If you are leaning back in your chair with your eyes closed, a passer-by does not need to see your face to see that you are not working. It doesn't matter whether you're resting your eyes, meditating, or actually napping, that's what it looks like.

The question is is this ok to do on your lunch break. The obvious answer is "yes, it' your break". The actual answer is "no, your boss said you can't nap at your desk whether you're supposed to be working or not."

There are potential reasons for this. Even though you don't need to be working, it looks like you're slacking off. It can also be frustrating to find someone at their desk but unresponsive.

You have three practical options here:

- Rest in the break room instead
- Eschew naptime
- Find a job that suits you better

Answer (score 0):

This post asks a bunch of questions that are not important.

The real question is: am I acting in an acceptable manner at this worksite?

That question cannot be answered by people on the internet.
However, let me share that impressions are important in any work environment. People walking by get an impression of your work habits by how you act. They will respond to those impressions, not to any reality.

Let me give some examples. I heard of one programmer who always acted as if he was under stress, running from place to place, never walking, staying later than the boss, and looking like he was working really hard. He quietly admitted to another worker that it was all an act. He actually hardly anything. Yet, because of the impressions, he was the one given raises and a promotion.

At another work location, one programmer always waited 5-10 minutes after the boss left to leave. Yep, she was the one promoted. Another person learned how to talk to the bosses and while his work was some of the most poorly designed and bug filled, he was promoted to "software architect".

An old story goes that the boss at a media company called a supervisor in and demanded that he fire person X. "Because every time I walk by, he is staring out the window." The supervisor replied that person X was the person who came up with several highly profitable shows. The boss didn't know what that person did, but was only going by the impressions of work habits.

So, because you have gotten some feedback, it might help to ask what are acceptable practices at that location.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the ugly. That is valuable information that I want to hear.